# Cоответствие слова современным нормам " правильного русского языка"

Tags: лексика

Доброе утро! Будьте любезны, поясните пожалуйста: с точки зрения не простонародного, а правильного, в узком значении этого слова, русского языка - будет-ли корректным употребление глагола "мочь"(что делать)???      Мне кажется, что данное слово заменить глаголом "уметь" можно не в каждом случае. Например: если речь идёт не о каких-либо приобретённых навыках ("уметь говорить", имея язык), а о возможности как таковой ("мочь говорить", не имея языка) или же о воле человека ("не уметь убивать" -  не знать, как это делать - не то же самое, что "не мочь убивать" - не решиться на совершение самого тяжкого греха)...           Спасибо... Извиняюсь...  Вижу, что я  не правильно сформулировал свой вопрос в целом.  Получилось, что сам же и ответил на основную его часть.... И всё же, будет ли считаться правильным выражение: "Мочь говорить - значит иметь язык"?  Еще раз спасибо. С уважением, Юрий.

Answer (score 3):

Глагол "мочь" в русском языке редко используется в инфинитиве, в прямом же модальном значении (т.е. в сочетании с другим глаголом в инфинитиве же) - вообще почти никогда. 
Поэтому во всех Ваших примерах его правильно заменить на "уметь" или "быть способным".
При этом в личных формах ("я не могу убивать") - вполне возможно. Однако следует иметь в виду, что при таком использовании сохраняется некоторая неоднозначность, поскольку "не могу" здесь может означать: а) моральный запрет, б) физическую неспособность, в) отсутствие навыка или способностей. А в других случаях могут быть еще варианты: "Я не могу есть эту пищу" - религиозный запрет, медицинские показания, пресыщенность, вкусовые предпочтения и т.п. Поэтому при возможности стОит и тут избегать использования "мочь" при наличии нужного синонима. Не знаю, что тут еще можно добавить.

Answer (score 2):

Глаголы «мочь» и «уметь» – разные как по происхождению, так и по значению. Глагол «мочь» обозначает «быть в состоянии, иметь возможность»,  а глагол «уметь»  –  «обладать навыком или способностью». Тем не менее,  нам порой кажется, что они обозначают примерно одно и то же.

Например: я могу читать, я умею читать. Мы считаем, что эти выражения близки по значению и взаимозаменяемы, однако в данном случае они просто являются СБЛИЖЕННЫМИ.  В действительности здесь причинно-следственная  связь:  я МОГУ читать, потому что я УМЕЮ читать.

Или подробнее: Я МОГУ читать  (ИМЕЮ ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ это осуществить), потому что УМЕЮ читать (меня научили читать).

Но:  Я НЕ МОГУ  (НЕ ИМЕЮ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ) убивать людей, потому что это противоречит моим убеждениям. Я убежден, что любая жизнь  неприкосновенна.  Поэтому в данном случае мое умение стрелять просто не имеет к отношения к этой теме.